# Using interface on ASP.NET MVC html helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I have the following method:

```
public static string UlList(this HtmlHelper helper, List<IEntity> entities, string css)
{
    return "foo";
}
```

However when i try and call the method

```
<%= Html.UlList(Model.ProfileRequiredFields, css)%>
```

I get:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'UlList' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelpers.UlList(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, System.Collections.Generic.List, string)' has some invalid arguments

```
Model.RequiredFields = new List<ProfileRequiredField>();

public class ProfileRequiredField : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT
I'm using 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do, with `List<IEntity>` as the parameter type,  works only in .NET 4.0 because of the new `out` keyword.

**If you need this to work in lower versions, try the following:**

```
public static string UlList<T>(this HtmlHelper helper, List<T> entities, string css)
    where T : IEntity
{
    return "foo";
}
```

This replaces `IEntity` with a generic argument. .NET will automatically resolve this for you, so you don't have to add `<ProfileRequiredField>` in your code.

Comment: ok, so can i not use this is Net 3.5. It doesn't really need to be an extension method.

Comment: No, you can't use `List<IEntity>` in 3.5. The above with the generic is specifically to make this work in 3.5 :). Clarified the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure your extension method is in the System.Web.Mvc namespace, or include your namespace in the list of namespaces defined in the web.config file.

Comment: -1 No. The compiler already sees the method, otherwise it wouldn't have detected that the arguments are incorrect.

Comment: Deducting a point is a bit trite. It is a perfectly valid thing to check for. There may have been multiple versions of the extension written in different namespaces for all you knew.